# R - sqldf - update query

Tags: sql, r, sqldf, rsqlite

I am currently working on a project where I need to update variables in my dataframe conditionally. I found the simplest way to do this would be to use sqldf/RSQLite. I have tried several code combinations so far and this is the one that I've got the furthest with (anonymising the dataset)

```
sqldf("UPDATE dataframe SET Variable = 'New Text Value' WHERE Variable.name.category = 'Text Value'")
```

From the research that I have done on the topic, I understand that sqldf has issues with the '.' character. Is there a simple workaround for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unlike R, dot is an operator. in SQL so if you want to use a variable name that contains a dot you must double quote the variable name.  This is not an issue with sqldf but is how SQL works.  Also note that `update` does not return a value so you need to use `c('update dataframe ...', 'select * from dataframe')` to actually return something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to conditionally update something is this:

```
dataframe$Variable[dataframe$Variable.name.category == "Text Value"] <- "New Text Value"
```

No need for sqldf at all.

The concept is called *logical indexing*. You index into the column `Variable` of your data frame based on the truth value of a logical expression `dataframe$Variable.name.category == "Text Value"`.

Another option is with `dplyr`:

```
dataframe <- dataframe %>%
  mutate(Variable = ifelse(
    Variable.name.category == "Text Value", 
    "New Text Value", 
    Variable)
  )
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew I'd made life complicated for myself